# Почему не работает js код?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть функция, которая должна переворачивать массив (как метод reverse):

```js
function reversed(arr) {
  for (var i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
    var elem = arr.pop();
    arr.unshift(elem);
  }
  return arr;
}

var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log(reversed(testArr));
```

Но возвращается исходный массив

Comment: Метод unshift не сортирует весь массив в обратном порядке, то есть не делает первый элемент - последним, второй - предпоследним  и т. п. К тому же глупо пользуясь этим методом, передавать ему по одному элементу. Внимательнее прочтите [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ezk94dwt(v=vs.94).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка логики - всё равно что пытаться перевернуть стопку, каждый раз беря сверху и подкладывая снизу.

```js
function reversed(arr) {
  for (var reversed = []; arr.length > 0; reversed.push(arr.pop()));
  return reversed;
}

var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
console.log(reversed(testArr));
```